# Started JBOSS Service via Shell Script, but hanging

Tags: shell

I managed to start JBOSS service through a shell script running locally inside the server.

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    {
            sh /jboss-6.1.0.Final/bin/run.sh -c server1 -g app1 -u x.x.x.x -b x.x.x.x -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=1 &
    }; fi
```

My problem is I am able to start the service and found the application working, but once the script finishes running, it is not returning to shell ($ prompt) back and keep on hanging there forever. When I run the same command directly (without script), after the command finishes running, on hitting Enter key, I can get my $ prompt and I shall do other works.

Can someone tell me what I am missing in my code so that I can return back to my $ prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Remove & from the shell script. Also remove {} from if block , no need.

Comment: Hello Himanshu, If I remove & at the end, I cannot come out of the script. I have to leave the terminal open. Only with the & symbol, I make sure the service is running, even If I exit the terminal.

Comment: use like this  if  [ condition ] then sh **Command** & fi.  You can automate this from cron and run it every 5 minutes. You can also check from script whether JBOSS is running or not and in case it is not then only start it.